# Java: How to stop a Executable jar which never terminates

Tags: java, jar, kill-process

I have a runnable jar which won't shutdown. i have executed it in my windows machine by double clicking on it. How can i terminate that application.

I dont what to kill all java.exe processes as i want other apps to run

Comment: start it using the command line, and when you close up the terminal, the jar will also quit. Or press `CTRL` + `C`

Comment: Determine this executable jar's process on windows task manager and kill that process.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are three options:

- Start in commandline with `java -jar [YourJarPath]` (Close by (Ctr + C) or close your commandline
- Restart your Windows
- Terminate it per TaskManager (Ctr+Alt+Del)

Under "Details" [image: TaskManager Taskbar]

Then look for "javaw.exe". Right Click and then something like Shutdown or exit Task.
[image]

To find the jar name, start in cmd (commandline) this code:

`C:\Program Files\Java\[YOUR JAVA VERSION]\bin\jps.exe`

it will return something like this:
[image: Img]

The number befor the "name" is your `PID` that is also listed in the taskmanager right next to `javaw.exe`

Comment: Thanks for your response.
Could you please help me in understanding how to find which one of the running processes is my intended one(can I find the Jar name or something similar for the processes).

Comment: @user3629658 I updateded my answer. Maybe this helps :). If it helps, you can maybe accept my answer :)

Answer (score 4):

`jps -v`

Will list all running jars along with their PID. Then you can just kill that process (with `kill $PID`)

Answer (score 1):

JVM starts new `java.exe` process each time you run `jar`. Obviously because jar starting is performed as `java -jar <jar_name>`.

So by locating exact process which holds your jar's process you can safely kill without worrying about rest java apps.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Could you please elaborate on how to find which process holds my jar.